# Creating a hierarchy in my ViewModels corresponding to the hierarchy of my Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel

I am creating a page in ASP.NET. On this page there are a few parts which I generalize using partial views. For example, I have a pair page with information about two persons on the page and I generalize using a person partial view.

When I am using this data in my controller on an action I use a `PairViewModel` to represent the data on my pair view. I would say, I represent each person partial view with a `PersonViewModel`. My `PairViewModel` will have two references to two `PersonViewModels`.

I have to somehow map the `PersonViewModels` in the `PairViewModel` with the partial views in the pair view. How would I specify this?

Also when I perform a post action. In the controller I would define a function

```
public ActionResult MyAction(PairViewModel pair)
```

The framework transfers the values of the view to the `PairViewModel` (not 100% sure about this) by the mapping I specified in view or automatically by looking at the member names and names of fields on the view. How would it map the values of the partial views onto the `PersonViewModel` instances in the `PairViewModel`?

Background:
I am new to ASP.NET and the use of ViewModels. I have used ViewModels a bit in WPF before and tried to put some hierarchy in them as well. What I go in the end was quite ok, but still seemed a bit messy on some points. As for my experience with ASP.NET, I just finished the Nerd Dinner tutorial and that's about it :).

Thanks in advance.